# How to get Android In-App Subscription auto renewal details?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app, auto-renewing

I'm working an app that will have an in-app subscription purchases on Weekly,Monthly bases.

When a user subscribe weekly or monthly, app getting subscription purchase details with OrderID like **GPA.0000-0000-0000-00000** and purchased date in long.

And as per the [Android developer blog](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#payment) after auto renewal we will get new order id with suffix ..1,..2,..3

**GPA.0000-0000-0000-00000..0**

**GPA.0000-0000-0000-00000..1**

**GPA.0000-0000-0000-00000..2**

**GPA.0000-0000-0000-00000..3**

But, my problem is after renewing the subscription also I'm still getting old subscription purchase details. No changes in OrderID and Purchased Date.

So, please anyone help me to get the Subscription Renewal Details.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a log we can look at?    and code so we can find the issue

Comment: Did you got a solution for this question? I'm also facing the same problem. Please help if you have an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi., have you found the solution ? .. me too having the same problem

Comment: Does anyone found solution?. I am getting this problem in production app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If a recurring payment fails (for example, because the customer’s credit card has become invalid), the subscription does not renew.

The **getPurchases()** method does not return failed or expired subscriptions.

At each subscription renewal, Google Play charges the user account automatically, then notifies the user of the charges afterward by email. For monthly and annual subscriptions, billing cycles will always match subscription cycles, based on the purchase date. (Seasonal subscriptions are charged annually, on the first day of the season.)

Refer for more details [In-app Subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

Comment: My subscription renewal is successfully done. I got renewal receipt to my gmail account. But, still I'm not getting the SubscriptionRenewal details in app. 

Thanks for the reference link. I've gone trough that, but still I'm not getting the renewal details in my app. 

Could you please help me in that?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?. I am still getting cached outdated purchase result.